# What is a scalable replacement for Windows Home Server backup technology?

Tags: backup, windows-home-server

We are up to three Windows Home Servers on site.  They happily sit unassumingly in the corner of the server room each backing up a combination of 10 computers/servers.

Benefits of WHS.

- Daily incremental image based backups of each machine.
- Saves disk space by consolidating duplicate bits across images.
- Easy access to files within an image through a fool proof UI.
- Simple image based recovery, again, through a fool proof UI.
- Did I mention a fool proof UI?  I mean the thing is dead simple to use for backup AND recovery.

Our only problem at this point is keeping a list tracking which WHS a given network computer was originally connected to.  I'd love something as simple but that can handle 30+ machines at once.  Is there anything out there?

Comment: P.S. - If someone with 2000+ reputation reads this can you please suggest consolidating the three Windows Home Server tags?  Thanks.

Comment: Ook, that's a messy set of tags.

Comment: Why are you backing up PCs? The users should have their important data residing on a file server and then just back that up regularly.

Comment: Synonyms created.

Comment: @MarkM: Accepting that business data should be on a server computer there can be some utility to backing-up machines that have a complex software load and aren't able to be re-created by a simple "re-join the domain and let the software load from Group Policy" solution. The Windows SBS backup functionality is reasonably unique. I'd love to see a product offering with similiar functionality for a reasonable price. The server-side block-level deduplicated data store alone is enough to "sell" me.

Comment: @MarkM: What Evan said.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I use this:
http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/

And I think it is the coolest backup technology ever.  It is linux, so you may have to deal with some issues, but I think it works well.  It is file based however, I don't know about Windows Home Server, but backuppc doesn't do images.